# How do I display a link as plain text in a README file

Tags: c#, asp.net, github, bitbucket, readme

I am writing a README file and I want to display the text "ASP.NET" in the file, but it displays as a link. Is there a way to force a URL (or text that looks like a URL) to display as plain text?

Comment: can you please type the code that you use to display this text ? There are few ways, but its depend how and where you try to place it

Comment: - ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have various ways to [Disable Github-flavored Markdown autolinking](https://gist.github.com/alexpeattie/4729247)

For example:

```
https://<!--This is a comment-->gist.github.com/<!--This is, too-->alexpeattie/4729247
# give:
https://gist.github.com/alexpeattie/4729247
```

Try also a code block: `https://your/url`, if you don't mind the code presentation.

Comment: I did try the back tics, but didn't like the presentation. The other example you provided _did_ work. Thank you @VonC